# Design Singleton Pattern - Constructor

Tags: java, singleton

I am unable to create an object using singleton design pattern, here is what I did:

```
class Test {
    public static Test objTest = null;
    public static int count = 0;

    public static Test CreateObject() {
        if (objTest != null)
            objTest = new Test(); 
        return objTest;
    }

    private Test() {
        Test.count++;
    }
}
```

Have I created zeroton pattern ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your if condition inside `createObject` method once. it should be `if(objTest == null)` .

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact, that your count would always be either '0' or '1' (ignoring potential multi-threading issues) - why do you have that parameter?

You are checking for `objTest != null` instead of `objTest == null`.

That's why you are always returning `null` and never create a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

The objTest variable should also be private, you'll not want to reference to a null instance. Access to the instance should only be possible through your CreateObject() method.